# remove tablespaces from pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, sed, sh

I am trying to write a script to import a database schema from a remote machine that only accepts ssh connections to a local one.

I managed to do anything except keep the same encoding has the remote database.

I found out that the solution was using pg_dump with -C (create) and that way I would be able to create the database with the same encoding but I faced a problem... there is a table space in the remote database and I dont want to import it.

I know that recent versions of psql already have the no-tablespace argument... but unlucky me, I'm not allowed to upgrade the postgres version.

Could someone tell me a way to remove all the tablespace ocurrences on a sql dump? like with sed or something.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to switch tablespaces between installations by piping pg_dump through `sed` where I altered the `TABLESPACE` clause.

You can also just remove it and additionally remove `CREATE TABLESPACE ...` from the dump file with any editor and you are good to load it to another DB cluster.

I long since moved on to newer versions where I can use the [`--no-tablespaces`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-OPTIONS) option. Depending on your setup, a shell command could look something like this in Linux - from the top of my head, only tested cursory:

```sh
pgdump -h 123.456.7.89 -p 5432 mydb \
| sed \
 -e' /^CREATE TABLESPACE /  d' \
 -e 's/ *TABLESPACE .*;/;/' \
 -e "s/SET default_tablespace = .*;/SET default_tablespace = '';/"
| psql -p5432 mylocaldb
```

- `-e' /^CREATE TABLESPACE /  d'` ... delete lines beginning with "CREATE TABLESPACE ".
- `-e 's/ *TABLESPACE .*;/;/'` ... trim the tablespace clause (always at the end of the line in pg_dump output) from `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE INDEX` statements.
- `-e "s/SET default_tablespace = .*;/SET default_tablespace = '';"` .. do away with any other default tablespace than the empty string - which signifies the default tablespace of the current db. Note the use of double quote `"`, so I can easily enter single quotes `'`.

If you know the name of the tablespace involved you can narrow this down. There is a theoretical possibility that a data line could start like one of the search terms. I have never encountered problems myself, though.

Check out [a page like this](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for more info on `sed`.

Comment: yeah the problem is that I need to have that in a script so the sed command to remove the tablespace would be best solution... althought I don't fully understand sed I dont know how should the sed command be to remove it

Comment: I had figured it out by myself hehehe used sed s/TABLESPACE/;--TABLESPACE or something like that

Comment: @Killercode: Should work, too - except for `CREATE TABLESPACE` and `SET default_tablespace` if those should be there.